# Can I use Giant Talon as a road bicycle?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, tire, hybrid-bike, giant

I bought a Giant Talon bike and I got thinner tires.

Can I use it for road and streets now?

Comment: You can use a clown's unicycle as a road bike.  Whatever is comfortable and has reasonable handling characteristics.

Comment: Any bike can be used on road - it might not be as fast, but there's no reason it can't go on-road.  Please expand your question with why it might not be suitable for on-road usage ?

Comment: [Product page for the Talon](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/bikes-talon). It's a suspension-fork MTB. If you are looking to convert it to a road bike, you are looking at buying two road bikes' worth of after-market parts.

Comment: Yes, you can ride a MTB on the road. It won't be the most efficient bike but if it works for you that's fine. You don't strictly need thinner tires but slick or lightly treaded ones help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use it (Giant Talon) for road and streets now?

Yes you can. Here's your bike (if you have a 2020 Talon 2)

[image]

There are some good reasons to use a mountain bike as a road touring bike. Here is one example:
[image]

And they make fine commuter bikes.

Sometimes people will put drop handlebars on their mountain bike for better aerodynamics. Sometimes, as you have done, people will use narrower smoother tires.

**It's all about trade offs**
A pure road bike will be more aerodynamic and be configured (weight, riding position, gearing, etc.) for a higher top speed.

A mountain bike will give you more ruggedness, (given the condition of roads in some places this can be a big bonus) a lower top speed, and more comfort. If this meets your needs you will be happy.

**Ride what you have and learn**
At the end of the day ride what you have and learn what does and does not work for you and adjust along the way. Saddle time is the best way to learn.